# Optimizing a "distinct where equals" query and indices

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize a query that looks something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(some_attribute)
FROM some_table
WHERE soft_deleted=0
```

I already have indices on `some_attribute` and `soft_deleted` individually.

The table from which I am pulling from is relatively large(>100GB), so this query can take tens of minutes. Would a multi-column index on some_attribute and soft_deleted make a significant impact or are there some other optimizations that I can make?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say the query plan is?

Comment: The query plan is a single simple non-unique key lookup using the soft_deleted index

Comment: because `soft_deleted` has only two values, it's useless to have an index on it (the optimizer knows it's faster to just scan the table). Define a *covering* index on both soft_deleted, some_attribute and you might have some luck.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that apply when a vast majority of the soft_deleted values are 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to assume this table is using InnoDB storage engine, and assume that `soft_deleted` column is integer-ish datatype, and that `some_attribute` column is a smallish datatype column.

For the exact query text shown in the question, optimal execution plan will likely make use of an index with `soft_deleted` and `some_attribute` as the leading columns in that order, i.e.

```
... ON some_table (soft_deleted, some_attribute, ...)
```

The index will also contain the columns from the cluster index (even if they aren't listed), so we could also include the names of those columns in the index following the two leading columns. MySQL will also be able to make use of an index that includes additional columns, again, following the two leading columns.

---

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan.

I expect the optimal execution plan will include "Using index for GROUP BY" in the Extra column, and avoid a "Using filesort" operation.

With the index suggested above, compare the execution plan for this query:

```
SELECT t.some_attribute
  FROM some_table t
 WHERE t.soft_deleted = 0  
 GROUP 
    BY t.soft_deleted 
     , t.some_attribute
 ORDER 
    BY NULL
```

---

If we already have an index defined with `some_attribute` as the leading column, and also including the `soft_deleted` column, e.g.

```
... ON some_table (some_attribute, soft_deleted, ... )
```

(an index on just the some_attribute column would be redundant, and could be dropped)

we might re-write the SQL and check the EXPLAIN output for a query like this:

```
SELECT t.some_attribute
  FROM some_table t
 GROUP 
    BY t.some_attribute
     , IF(t.soft_deleted = 0,1,0)
HAVING t.soft_deleted = 0
 ORDER
    BY NULL
```

If we have a guarantee that `soft_deleted` only has two distinct values, then we could simplify to just

```
SELECT t.some_attribute
  FROM some_table t
 GROUP 
    BY t.some_attribute
     , t.soft_deleted
HAVING t.soft_deleted = 0
 ORDER
    BY NULL
```

---

Optimal performance of a query against this table, to return the specified resultset, is likely going to be found in an execution plan that avoids a "Using filesort" operation and using an index to satisfy the DISTINCT/GROUP BY operation.

---

Note that `DISTINCT` is a keyword not a function. The parens around `some_attribute` have no effect, and can be omitted. (Including the spurious  parens almost makes it look like we think `DISTINCT` is a function.)